# maven default heap space and Permgen size

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

According to [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781783983865/1/ch01lvl1sec10/configuring-the-heap-size) :

> Once you have installed Maven in your system, the next step is to
>   fine-tune it for optimal performance. By default, the maximum heap
>   allocation is 256 - 512 MB (-Xms256m to -Xmx512m). This default limit
>   does not work while building a large, complex Java project, and it is
>   recommended that you have at least 1024 MB of maximum heap.

Now, I think heap space and permgen space max and min values are set by JVM. Maven can only set them by MAVEN_OPTS env variable which is set by us. So, where are those values be set as default by maven ?

If that be true , what is default max , min set for permgen size by maven for itself ?

I am taking of Java 7 and maven 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the heap space etc. are set by the JVM which you correctly mentioned.

Furthermore you can set them for [Maven via `.mvn/jvm.config`](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html) or as you already mentioned via `MAVEN_OPTS` as mentioned.

The `MAVEN_OPTS` and maybe other things (for example JAVA_HOME) can also be defined via the `.mavenrc` which is located in `$HOME/.mavenrc`(Linux/Mac) or `%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.bat` or `%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd` (Windows):

So a `.mavenrc` file could contain:

```
export JAVA_HOME=.../jdk-11.0.1.jdk
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2g"
```

or another option would be to use a `jvm.config` (located within the project in `.mvn` directory) file could contain:

```
-Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

There are no default values defined by Maven. The default values are the ones which are defined by the JVM.

For Java 7 I would recommend not to change the PermGen cause this is usually needed if you deploy into servlet containers like Tomcat or real application servers etc. But of course it depends.

Furthermore the quote from the book I would simply say. Just start with the defaults. If we are talking about performance you should really check if the problem is really the memory which I usually doubt. There is of course an influence there which which has an impact if we are talking about builds which have 100+ modules within a single multi module build.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. One doubt though. Suppose I mention my local maven config in `jvm.config` and commit this file too in remote git repository. Now, build my project in a remote server. Config to run build on this server can be different from what I mentioned in `jvm.config`. Will it create conflict ?

Comment: In `jvm.config` only configuration for the JVM should be part of  it?

Comment: Correct. But what if I wanted to provide different java config for my maven at remote build machine ? Such use case can arise ?

Comment: First I doubt that it makes sense having different JVM configuration between local machine and your build machine apart from that your configuration in your CI server should be doing it correctly..